# django-registration Template not showing user logged in

Tags: django, registration, django-registration

I am using the current version of django and using [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/)

I got everything working on the server, and I got the templates done, with the help of [this blog](http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/).

sometimes the page show's the user logged in, other times the same base.html say's that the user is not logged in.  I think I have to pass the user to the template but I have no idea what to lookup, the docs on this stop after it's set up.  How can I get this Base.html to work, It say's that I'm not logged in.  then I go to the loggin page and it then say's on that page that I am logged in.

It seems to be url specific. It will say that I am logged in, move to a different page, and it offers me to get logged in. Why can't I have it site wide, what am I missing

django-registration is a package  so I don't know what I can do, Change the view Function?
the following is my base.html

```
 {% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}User test{% endblock %}</title>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        {% block header %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% trans "Logged in" %}: {{ user.username }} 
    (<a href="{% url auth_logout %}">{% trans "Log out" %}</a> | 
    <a href="{% url auth_password_change %}">{% trans "Change password" %}</a>)
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url auth_login %}">{% trans "Log in" %}</a>
    {% endif %}
    <hr />
        {% endblock %}
    </div>


    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        {% block footer %}
        <hr />
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the view code but I suspect that your issue relates to the fact that you didnt pass a RequestContext on all of your views functions.

The User variable in the templete is added by a context processor.

just do :

```
ctx = RequestContext(request)
```

in your view function and pass it to the templete processor by :

```
context_instance=ctx
```

Comment: thank you very much, I need to do some learning about the 'Context'  I had to add this to make it work: from django.template import RequestContext  Plus the code needs to stay In the view function, otherwise the server does not know 'request' so I just added the whole thing"context_instance = RequestContext " to the return of the view, I'll need it on all of my views, and could not create a variable ctx outside of the view.   Thanks a lot it saved me a lot of stress